# How do I find the determinant of a n-th row matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

[How do I solve this type of matrix?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fAEK.png)

I don't know what's the best approach, which row should I deduct, which should I add. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try to put in triangular form by adding to the secod row the oppsite of the third and so on